# Link not forming correctly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink, helper

I am trying to create a link with two classes.

Code in my view looks like this:

```
<%= link_to "back", controller: "welcome", :class => "btn test" %>
```

And am expecting to have:

```
<a href="/welcome/index" class="btn primary">back</a>
```

But am getting:

```
<a href="/welcome/index?class=btn+test">back</a>
```

What is that am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to):

```
<%= link_to "back", { controller: "welcome" }, :class => "btn test" %>
```